# Python で時刻を表す文字列の引き算

Tags: python

現時点から直近の出発時刻を求める方法探しています。
現在時刻とタイムテーブルを4桁の数字に変換し，引き算をすれば良いと考えたのですが、以下の問題が生じております。
どなたかよい方法をご教授いただければ幸いです。

↓時刻データの状態

```
arrived_time = ['1216', '1337', '1018', '1809', '2058', '1919'...]
time_table = ['1210', '1230', '1305', '1328', '1400', '1411'...]
```

例えば1216から1210を引くと6分の差があることがわかるのですが，1216から1130を引いた場合86となってしまい計算不可能になります。

Comment: 情報不足ですみません....更新しました.
現時点の時刻がarrived_dataで，この各中身について，もっとも直近の時刻をtime_tableから探し，その時間差分を求めたいのです。そのため日付は要らず，正しく算出できれば差分の分数が得られます。

Comment: リストの中のどれとどれの差分ですか？ 隣り合う要素間あるいは総当たりとか。あと日付の情報は不要なのですか？ 基本的には時刻情報なのだから、文字列ではなく時刻情報に変換して計算すれば良いでしょう。[datetime --- 基本的な日付型および時間型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html), [timedelta オブジェクト](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), [time オブジェクト](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects)

Comment: 誰か/何かの出発時刻と対応する到着時刻が例えば同じインデックス位置に無い場合があるのでしょうか？ それは何かを管理するデータとしては甚だしく品質が悪いのでは？ 何にも紐付けされない時刻データが並んでいるというのは、それ自身を改善すべきと思われます。

Comment: payaneco さんの回答に「特定の駅の時刻表」という質問に無いキーワードが出ていますが、そういった特定の背景や事情の有る処理に関する質問ならば、それらの情報や要件も質問に追記されれば的確な助言や回答を得られ易いでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

時分を10進数で計算していることが問題です。
単位を分にそろえてから減算すれば期待する結果が得られます。

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
t1 = dt.strptime('1216', '%H%M')
t2 = dt.strptime('1130', '%H%M')
d = (t1.hour*60+t1.minute) - (t2.hour*60+t2.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

特定の駅の時刻表である`time_table`が用意されていて、ソートされていない時刻データの直近の値を取り出す場合は[ラムダ式を使う](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141207)方法があります。

「直近」が文字通り「差分の最も少ない前後の時刻」ならば`datetime`の差分で求めた`timedelta`が最も小さいものを取ると良いでしょう。
「直近」が「直前」「直後」ならば、結局何分差かを求める際に`timedelta`が必要ですが、比較自体は内包表記による文字列比較で対応可能です。

```
from datetime import datetime

arrived_time = ['1216', '1337', '1018', '1809', '2058', '1919', '1159']
time_table = ['0000', '1140', '1210', '1230', '1305', '1328', '1400', '1411', '1900', '2359']

for at in arrived_time:
    dat = datetime.strptime(at, '%H%M')
    immediate = min(time_table, key = lambda x:abs(datetime.strptime(x, '%H%M') - dat))  # 直近
    immediate = max([t for t in time_table if t <= at])  # 直前
    immediate = min([t for t in time_table if t > at])   # 直後

    diff = datetime.strptime(immediate, '%H%M') - dat
    minutes = abs(diff.total_seconds() / 60)
    print('"{}"の直近は"{}"で、{}分差です。'.format(at, immediate, int(minutes)))
```

Answer (score 0):

いろいろコメントしましたが、@payaneco さんが示したように乗り換え案内的な処理を考えているなら、まあ普通に考えられるケースということでしょうか。

時刻の差分計算はコメントに紹介したり、先に回答されているようにdatetimeモジュール(ライブラリ?)を使います。
例えば @akira ejiri さんと @payaneco さんの処理の組み合わせで以下のように出来ます。

```
diff = str(int((dt.strptime(出発時刻,"%H%M") - dt.strptime(現時点,"%H%M")).total_seconds() // 60))
```

ただし提示された条件ならば、全部のデータを時刻に変換してから差分計算を行う必要は無くて、直近(直後)の出発時刻を見つけてから計算しても問題無いでしょう。
時刻情報は4桁の数字なので単に文字列の上下としてソートできます。

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

arrived_time = ['1216', '1337', '1018', '1809', '2058', '1919']
time_table = ['1210', '1230', '1305', '1328', '1400', '1411']

#### それぞれの時刻にどちらの情報かの属性を付けて1つにまとめる
t_arv = [[a,1] for a in arrived_time]
t_dpt = [[d,2] for d in time_table]
t_arv.extend(t_dpt)

#### 時刻情報でソートする(4桁の数字なので単に文字列の上下としてソートできる)
t_mix = sorted(t_arv, key=lambda x: x[0])
t_mix_atr = [e[1] for e in t_mix]    #### 検索のために現/出発の属性だけのリスト化

#### 現時点と直近の出発時刻のペアと差分を調べる処理
list_result = []
items = len(t_mix)
for i in range(items):
    if t_mix[i][1] == 1:  #### 現時点情報なら処理を始める/出発時刻情報なら処理しない
        try:
            j = t_mix_atr[i:].index(2)    #### 以後の直近の出発時刻のインデックスを取得
            arv = t_mix[i][0]
            dpt = t_mix[i+j][0]
            #### 文字列を時刻に変換し、差分の値を分単位に計算して文字列化
            diff = str(int((dt.strptime(dpt,"%H%M") - dt.strptime(arv,"%H%M")).total_seconds() // 60))
            list_result.append([arv,dpt,diff])    #### 結果リストに追加
        except:
            pass

for r in list_result:
    print(f'現時点：{r[0]},  出発時刻：{r[1]},  差分：{r[2]}分')
```